# Count second level set of model in nhibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I want to count set of set of model in NHibernate using Criteria Query.

Account Model have Contacts(set) and Contact Model have Addresses(set).

I want to count addresses by giving input Account object.

I have implemented temporary by simple foreach loop.

If anyone know then please help me.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: finally I found solution:

Comment: var count = (Int32)Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Account))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", account.Id))
                        .CreateCriteria("Contacts", "Contacts", JoinType.InnerJoin, Restrictions.IsNotEmpty("Addresses"))
                        .SetProjection(Projections.Count("Id")).UniqueResult();

Comment: Not sure why the down vote... it is interesting question, and your own answer is really nice. Please, take it from a comment and append it as real (later accept it as well) answer... it could be of some use later. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks  Radim Köhler,

I found my solution by :

`var count = (Int32)Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Account)) 
              .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", account.Id)) 
              .CreateCriteria("Contacts", "Contacts", JoinType.InnerJoin,       Restrictions.IsNotEmpty("Addresses")) 
              .SetProjection(Projections.Count("Id")).UniqueResult();` .

Then I have used following criteria query:

```
var count = (Int32)Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Address))
                    .CreateCriteria("Contact", "Contact",JoinType.InnerJoin)
                    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Account.Id",accountId))
                    .SetProjection(Projections.Count("Id")).UniqueResult();
```

This give me actual result that I want by optimal query.